# Term for Successful Sale after Demoing Product

Tags: terminology, business-language

I believe there is a business term for such an event, but I can't recall what it is.

An example would be a vacuum salesman showing a prospective buyer how a vacuum works, and the buyer ends up buying one.

Comment: That's known as "*closing* the sale" (or the deal).

Comment: *Conversion* -- from lead (prospective) to buyer. "In electronic commerce, conversion marketing is the act of converting site visitors into paying customers." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_marketing